# Can the Pi 4 output independent 7.1 audio to each hdmi port? (i.e. 16 audio channels)

Tags: audio, hdmi

I gather that the Pi can output 7.1 audio over HDMI. But can it send two different 7.1 audio outputs to each of the HDMI ports? i.e. for a total of 16 audio outputs (provided I can extract the audio from the HDMI signals)?